# Handling missing values in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the data as following

```
  Name   Location  profits loss sales    address      revenue  stocks
   AA     London     20      30    2    Lheigts,20109   54       45
   BB     Boston     NA      NA   NA    KicK,30029     NA        NA
   CC     Mumbai     NA      2     NA   New, 10023     43        NA
```

I would like to have output like this which will delete cases for which profits, loss, sales, revenue, stocks are completely missing. Any ideas?

```
   Name   Location  profits loss sales    address      revenue  stocks
   AA     London     20      30    2    Lheigts,20109   54        45
   CC     Mumbai     NA      2     NA   New, 10023     43        NA
```

Comment: You might check out the arcane function `is.na` and the obscure operator known as `&` :)

Comment: Also `rowSums` can help with `is.na` `df1[rowSums(!is.na(df1[c(3:5,7:8)]))!=0,]`

Comment: I tried this  `new<- df1[rowSums(!is.na(df1[c(3:5,7:8)]))!=0,]` but i am still seeing the NA's in the rows. Thanks!

Comment: I get the expected result you posted with that code, and your expected result also have some NAs so I don't know what you really wanted

Comment: let me check again more carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 df1[rowSums(!is.na(df1[c(3:5,7:8)]))!=0,]
```