# Handling missing values in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am dealing with time series data where I need to have continuous time stamps but few of the data timestamp points has been missed while capturing like as below,

`DF`

```
ID Time_Stamp             A           B                 C
1  02/02/2018 07:45:00   123          567               434     
2   02/02/2018 07:45:01    
.....                  ...

5   02/02/2018 07:46:00   
6   02/02/2018 07:46:10    112          2323            2323
```

As shown in the sample `df` above, time stamps is continuous till `row 5` but missed capturing data of `10 seconds` between `5th and 6th row`. My data frame is about `60000 rows` and identifying missing values manually is tedious. 
Hence I was looking for automating the procedure of handling missing values using R

My result data frame is as below,

```
ID Time_Stamp                     A           B                 C
1  02/02/2018 07:45:00           123          567               434     
2   02/02/2018 07:45:01    
.....                  ...

5   02/02/2018 07:46:00         mean(A)
5.1  02/02/2018 07:46:01        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.2  02/02/2018 07:46:02        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c) 
5.3  02/02/2018 07:46:03        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c) 
5.4  02/02/2018 07:46:04        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.5  02/02/2018 07:46:05        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.6  02/02/2018 07:46:06        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.7  02/02/2018 07:46:07        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.8  02/02/2018 07:46:08        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
5.9  02/02/2018 07:46:09        mean(A)     mean(b)         mean(c)
6   02/02/2018 07:46:10         112         2323            2323
```

Kindly Help!

Comment: Take a look at `mice`/`zoo`. In any case it's unclear what `mean(A)` means. Are you replacing all missing values with the mean? You simply say **handling missing values**, there are several imputation methods that have different uses.

Comment: @NelsonGon, Yes I am trying to replace the missing rows with mean value of that column. I tried with searching on imputation methods, most of them addressed on how to handle when there are `NA`. Rather I need to create rows with NA's between the skipped time intervals, and later replacing `NA` with mean is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to have a specific example showing specific expected output so that there is little space for ambiguity and assumption. However, I have created a dummy data based on my understanding and tried to solve it accordingly.

If I have understood you correctly, you have time series data with data point every second but sometimes there are some seconds missing which you want to fill it with `mean` of that column.

We can achieve this using `complete` by generating a sequence for every second between the `min` and `max` `Time_Stamp` and fill the missing values by the `mean` in the respective column. `ID` looks like an unique identifier for each row so filled it with `row_number()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(Time_Stamp = seq(min(Time_Stamp), max(Time_Stamp), by = "sec")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(A:C), ~replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) 


# A tibble: 11 x 5
#   Time_Stamp             ID     A     B     C
#   <dttm>              <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2018-02-02 07:45:00     1  123   567   434 
# 2 2018-02-02 07:45:01     2  234   100   110 
# 3 2018-02-02 07:45:02     3  234   100   110 
# 4 2018-02-02 07:45:03     4  176.  772.  744.
# 5 2018-02-02 07:45:04     5  176.  772.  744.
# 6 2018-02-02 07:45:05     6  176.  772.  744.
# 7 2018-02-02 07:45:06     7  176.  772.  744.
# 8 2018-02-02 07:45:07     8  176.  772.  744.
# 9 2018-02-02 07:45:08     9  176.  772.  744.
#10 2018-02-02 07:45:09    10  176.  772.  744.
#11 2018-02-02 07:45:10    11  112  2323  2323
```

If you check the column means for last 3 columns, you can see those value are accurately replaced.

```
colMeans(df[3:5])
#     A      B      C 
#175.75 772.50 744.25
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Time_Stamp = structure(c(1517557500, 
1517557501, 1517557502, 1517557510), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), A = c(123L, 234L, 234L, 112L), B = c(567L, 
100L, 100L, 2323L), C = c(434L, 110L, 110L, 2323L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

which looks like

```
df

#  ID          Time_Stamp   A    B    C
#1  1 2018-02-02 07:45:00 123  567  434
#2  2 2018-02-02 07:45:01 234  100  110
#3  3 2018-02-02 07:45:02 234  100  110
#4  4 2018-02-02 07:45:10 112 2323 2323
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, when I run your script it says `Error in seq.default(min(Timestamp), max(Timestamp), by = "sec") : 
  'from' must be a finite number`. Str(df) shows `TimeStamp` is "chr". Is it an issue with the typecasting?

Comment: @RahulK yes, you need to convert them to datetime from character. First do `df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %T")` and then apply the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to say about your issue:

- **Scientifically,** is there a motivation about replacing missing values which have a meaning) by meaned values?
- **Technically,** this might be done with a `*apply()` function (e.g. `lapply` fits pretty well data frames)
- **About R community,** this might be a reccurent question. Did you check some other posts elsewhere? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628341/handling-missing-data-in-r) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487333/handling-missing-values-in-r) which could help or give clues.
  I hope my answer will help you.